# Filling DataGridView from database

Tags: c#, database

I have a DataGridView which I want to fill from my database. I got an empty DataGridView. Here's my script and what I tried :

```
        private void listUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<User> lesUsers = Passerelle.getUsers();
        dgvUser.DataSource = lesUsers;
    }
```

My class :

```
class User
{
    private int id { get; set; }
    private int level { get; set; }
    private string name { get; set; }
    private string password { get; set; }
    private string email { get; set; }

    public User(int idP, int levelP, string nameP, string passwordP, string emailP)
    {
        id = idP;
        level = levelP;
        name = nameP;
        password = passwordP;
        email = emailP;
    }
}
```

And the way I got my data :

```
    public static List<User> getUsers()
    {
        MySqlDataReader result = executerSelect("SELECT id, level, name, email, password FROM users");
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        if(result != null)
        {
            while(result.Read())
            {
                int id = int.Parse(result[0].ToString());
                int level = int.Parse(result[1].ToString());
                string name = result[2].ToString();
                string email = result[3].ToString();
                string password = result[4].ToString();
                users.Add(new User(id, level, name, password, email));
            }

        }
        return (users.ToList());
    }
```

I already tried with a binding source but I'm not able to link with my datagridview

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign **`lesUsers`** , instead of **`getUsers`** which is a method

```
 List<User> lesUsers = Passerelle.getUsers();
 dgvUser.DataSource = lesUsers ;
```

**EDIT**

check if you have public properties which would be used to display the contents of the Class as columns in the DataGridView

Comment: This is a mistake while copying sorry! I have already assigned it but I got an absolute empty DataGridView...

Comment: Just tried your code and this is still not working... When I go for a debug, I can see my list being implemented by "User" with attributes, but I can't show it in my DataGridView, it stays still

Comment: one more thing, you need to chnge your properties to be public

Comment: private properties was the problem, thanks you for helping!